# Apex Convert Positive Currency to Negative Currency

Tags: apex, math, variable

I'm wondering if my syntax is off.  My varCreditRefundAmount is a positive value and when I add it to a new transaction representing a refund, I want to convert it to a negative amount.

This is what I'm doing:

```
            newTransaction.ChargentOrders__Amount__c = varCreditRefundAmount * -1;
```

But I'm getting the error: Arithmetic expressions must use numeric arguments

Is it my syntax or could I be doing something else wrong?  The value in the variable is a currency and the field I'm trying to send it to is also currency.

Thanks!

Comment: It'd help to have more context here. Can you [edit] your question to show us how `varCreditRefundAmount` is declared and set? Given the error, I suspect you've declared it as a `String`, but the less that other people have to guess the more accurate the answers you'll get.

Comment: I suspect `varCreditRefundAmount` may be holding a string value that looks like a currency: `'3.00'` for example - otherwise your logic is fine :)

Comment: You are right, I'm passing it as a string.  It's coming from a Flow and the input is currency in the flow so can I declare as currency in my apex or would it be integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some languages allow a bit more fluidity in data types (weakly/loosely typed languages), but not Apex. Apex is "strongly typed", which means that there's basically no flexibility. If something expects to be passed something like an `Integer` or `Decimal`, you can't pass it a `String` instead.

That's the case here. You're trying to multiply a string and a number, and since that operation isn't defined, you get an error.

If you're taking a currency, then you'd probably want to store that as a `Decimal` (`Double` would likely also work, but I believe `Decimal` is the better fit).

Changing the type of the input to your invocable method to be `Decimal` would be the preferred approach, I think. If for some reason that isn't possible, as long as you don't have currency symbols or decimal separators in your string, (e.g. `'3,000.00'` and `'$3000.00'` would be bad, but `'3000.00'` is fine), then you can use the `valueOf()` method provided by the `Decimal` class to convert it to a decimal.

e.g. `Decimal converted = Decimal.valueOf(givenInputString);`

Comment: Thank you!!  That seems to have solved my math error!

Comment: @Heather As a side note, you don't need to multiply by -1, you can also simply write `-myDecimalVar` or even `-Decimal.valueOf(myDecimalString)`.

Comment: @sfdcfox OK!  Thanks for that tip!